# How to use Java version 15 in Eclipse 2020-09

Tags: java, eclipse, java-15

I'm trying to run the new Java 15 features under Eclipse 2020-09.

I have installed OpenJDK 15 and set it under "Installed JRE":

[image: installed jres]

Nevertheless I cannot set this version as compiler version (only till version 14):

[image: Compiler level]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you install the plugin https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417 ?

Comment: @user7294900 clearly, nope. Repost that comment as an answer, I think :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eclipse needs a dedicated [plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417) to support Java 15.

> This marketplace solution provides Java 15 support for Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17)

Comment: Thanks. That should be the solution! But why isn't the version 15 support built in the newest Eclipse version? Imho it is very unfortunate, isn't it?

Comment: @mrbela This is because time travel has not yet been invented and will not be invented or when it will be invented, no one will travel back (or have traveled back?), which is reasonable in 2020, isn't it?

Comment: @howlger What do you mean? Maybe Eclipse 2020-09 was released to early to include version 15.. But, in the meantime, it could be possible to include this support?!

Comment: @mrbela Yes, it's possible. But for quality reasons the Java 15 support will be built-in starting with Eclipse 2020-12 (4.19) which will be released on December 16 (keep in mind that Eclipse has its own compiler, so not only adjustments in the editor are necessary). There are only a few who already use Java 15 and the support can be easily installed via Marketplace. You are free to build your own Eclipse with Java 15 support (which is quite easy and you can do it with a single command line call).

Comment: @howlger in mrbela defence eclipse released 1 day after Java 15 (September 16, 2020)

Comment: @user7294900 To be fair, one day is a bit short to implement Java 15 support in the Eclipse Compiler for Java (ecj) and in the Eclipse Java IDE. The release date is the date when you can download what was built and uploaded to the download mirrors a few days before. Which means to test the Java 15 support with the final Java 15 at least once, you would have to time travel.