# Plugin for Java 15 support in eclipse 2020-09 no longer available

Tags: java, eclipse, java-15

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64119888/how-to-use-java-version-15-in-eclipse-2020-09). I know you need to have [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-15-support-eclipse-2020-09-417) to support Java 15 in eclipse 2020-09, however, it doesn't seem to be available any longer.

When I try to install it via the marketplace, I am getting this error:

> No repository found at
> https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.17-P-builds/.

Is there a way to install it from other sources?

I know that eclipse 2020-12 has been released, but we cannot use it due to bug [#569498](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569498) (which didn't happen in eclipse 2020-09). So we would really need a way to install Java 15 support in eclipse 2020-09.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this on eclipse.org ? I've also reverted to 2020-09 as Eclipse 2020-12 has a dodgy compiler, and it does look like that "Java 15" plugin site is offline for the 2020-09 build (but fortunately I already have the Java 15 plugin in my copy).

Comment: I did so now: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1106384/

Comment: Can you try again now? I just rebuilt 4.17 patch build.

Comment: Seems to be working, see post below. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of regressions in 4.18, I decided to recreate 4.17-P-builds repository.

Please note this will be available till 4.19 is released or we decide to create a patch for 4.18 release.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A patch release for 4.18 would be very welcome, as I can see in https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569498, many people are having the same problem, and refactoring bigger parts of the code base is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I got a answer from the [eclipse forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1106384/)

> Java 15 support is included in eclipse 4.18(2020-12). As part of
> cleaning old releases we removed 4.17-P-builds repo as it is not
> supported anymore.
>
> Please upgrade to 2020-12 to continue work on java 15

Comment: Not very helpful response from the Eclipse site, you may need to wait for Eclipse 4.19 (which is where one of the compiler bugs fixes is due)

Comment: Yes, not very helpful indeed, now effectivbely both versions are unusable for me Do you have a reference for one of the bug fixes?

Comment: I'm not sure how many other there could be: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569498 . It is easy to workaround but I can't be bothered to edit all my projects, so will just wait for Eclipse 2021.

Comment: How is it easy to workaround? By changing the given lines of code?

Comment: Yes - that particular error can be fixed by removing final from boolean member flags used in ternary operators `flag ? "A" : "B"`, or by refactoring the expression value into a local variable such as `String s = flag ? "A" : "B"`

Comment: Still quite a lot of code to touch. Anyway, I observed smth like that. thanks!

Comment: Try to install the patch again now. i just recreated the 4.17-P-build repository

Comment: @Sravan wow looks good, the above URL is now recognized as an update site. Many thanks for that. You might want to post that as an answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: I dont have eclipse 2020-09 right now so I cannot test if I can actually install that, but looks good enough.